# Permission settings for Edit Node Link to show up?

Tags: views, nodes, users

I have a view that includes the `Node: Edit link` field. When the view gets rendered and the user is logged-in, only an Admin can see the link. What permission settings do I need to have enabled for that link to show up in a role with custom permissions?

**Additional details:**

`Edit link` was added to view in the standard way. See screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to Edit their own content or any content?

Answer (score 1):

go to:

> admin/people/permissions

and check:

> Content type name: Edit own content.

if you want that this role can edit **ANY** content of this type, not only their own conent, then check:

> Content type name: Edit any content.

Comment: Nope... I even rebuilt post permissions afterwards. Any other ideas?

Comment: how did u add the edit link in the view?

Comment: I added it in standard way... see the screenshot in the question. Does that help?

Comment: make sure u checked the right content type : Edit own content, and make sure that the user that is trying to edit the content is the actual author.

Comment: Okay... here's the absurd thing: I made my custom role an EXACT MATCH of the editor role's default permissions. Still noting. Then I switched my test user to Editor and it works. Back to custom... no dice. At this point, the two roles are identical. What???

Comment: just out of curiosity, who is the node author?

Comment: Hmm... I see where you're going here. The node author is me (admin). The test user hasn't authored any content.

Comment: try authoring something and we will go from there.

Comment: You know what... at this point, I just need this to work. So I'm going with the editor role and just disabling what don't need. So far so good.

Comment: If you use "Content type name: Edit own content" and then log-in as a user that didn't create the content, you will not see the "Edit" link.  You should: Create a user with desired role, create content, see if the link appears on your page/block, log-in as another user, go back to just created content - link should not be there.

Comment: @Sam you may want to check "Content type name: Edit any content" in permissions page, if you want that this role can edit **ANY** content of this type.

Answer (score 0):

Another factor to consider is whether your site is multilingual. *If so, providing role access to a given content type may not be enough*.

For example, if **Entity Translation** is used, you would want to check permissions settings under that heading on the admin/permissions/people page. This was stumping me on a site recently.

As always, **exercise extreme caution** as to how much control you give users. Even excepting malicious intent, a lot of things can go awry in the hands of inexperienced users.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code for the Views handler on the node edit link field, it performs a simple node_access check for update permission on the node.

```
class views_handler_field_node_link_edit extends views_handler_field_node_link {

  /**
   * Renders the link.
   */
  function render_link($node, $values) {
    // Ensure user has access to edit this node.
    if (!node_access('update', $node)) {
      return;
    }

    $this->options['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
    $this->options['alter']['path'] = "node/$node->nid/edit";
    $this->options['alter']['query'] = drupal_get_destination();

    $text = !empty($this->options['text']) ? $this->options['text'] : t('edit');
    return $text;
  }
}
```

So it's not something with Views -- other users just don't have permission to edit the content. And giving "Edit Any Content" permission to all users is not a good idea.

If you want to display the link regardless of whether or not they have access, just create a new Custom Field that is formatted as a link to the edit screen:

1) Click Add Fields for the view

2) Add the node NID number, and a Custom Text Field

3) make sure the node NID number is listed before the Custom Text field so that you can use it as a replacement.

4) Add a a custom field with the below value:

```
<a href="/node/[nid]/edit">Edit</a>
```